# Dynamically resizing elements using javascript and PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, resize

I have the following javascript code that I am attempting to use to resize a div.

```
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('.resizable-area1').height($(window).height() - 220);
    });

    $(window).trigger('resize');

});
```

I am doing this to make my content fit onto the screen. My div is set up as follows:

```
<div class="resizable-area1 span12" style="overflow-y:auto;" data-bind="foreach: app.windowDeliverySummary.viewList">
```

This all works fine in my web browser and on an Android emulator but upon transferring to my phone I start to encounter problems. When rendered in my phone the bottom (approximately 220 pixels) are inaccessible and to not respond to interactions. If I change the javascript above to just make the div the same size as the window I fix the previous problem but part of my div ends up off the screen and a scroll bar does not get generated as would be expected with overflow.

Can anyone suggest a way to get this to function correctly?

Comment: Have you tried triggering the resize event in onDeviceReady()?

Comment: @Coh3n The event triggers and resizes correctly. The problem is that upon doing so parts of my div become inaccessible. I have elements that can be clicked on and clicking on elements at the top of the div works but elements on the bottom of the div dont work.

Comment: Hmm, okay so by inaccessible to you mean it's completely off the screen? Because you also said it doesn't respond to interaction, implying you can see it on the screen. If you can make a JSFiddle, I can quickly throw it on my device and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: @Coh3n What i tried to explain in my original post is two different cases i was using to try to find the problem. When I use the resizing it sizes correctly but the bottom of my dev does not respond to interaction. When I dont resize it (or resize simply to the window size) I get elements that end up being off the screen (the scroll bar does not scroll far enough to see all the elements).  Ill see if I can get a JSFiddle to work but theres lots of code so im not sure that it'll be possible.

Comment: OH, okay that makes much more sense. :p Is there any time where your div does respond to interaction? Also, what kind of interaction? There are some that are different for mobile devices.

Comment: @Coh3n http://jsfiddle.net/qBR8h/ <--its not fully functioning but this should give you more of an idea of what im trying to describe. By interaction I mean clicking on the div (or in the case of a phone touching). The idea is that once I click an element its style changes to indicate that its selected. The odd thing is that it works for the top part of the div but not the bottom part. It seems like the bottom third of the phone just doesnt respond to the clicking, yet if I scroll down when the element that wasn't previously responding moves up it works again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the way you're handling the clicking events. Have you tried a simple $(".tile").click(); event rather than the data-bind attributes?

Comment: @Coh3n the click event is being handled by the knockout library for javascript. Basically what its doing is just running a custom js script on click. With a $(".tile").click() event I would not be able to determine which tile was clicked from what I understand. The way my click event is set up right now the js function receives data indicating which tile was clicked.

Comment: You can get which one was clicked if you have unique id's for each div then use a loop to check id's, but I don't think that would help you in this situation. I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help. :(

Comment: @coh3n I appreciate your attempt to help.